# How can I install Pandoc version 1.8.1.1?

Tags: 10.04, installation, package-management

I am having trouble getting a installing version 1.8.1.1 of pandoc. The repository has version 1.5.1.1, and the [1.8.1.1 tar.gz](http://code.google.com/p/pandoc/downloads/list) does not come with clear instructions for installation.

I have also tried the recommendation from the [pandoc page](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html):

```
sudo apt-get install cabal
cabal update 
cabal install pandoc
```

And pandoc is installed in `~/.cabal/lib/pandoc-1.8.1.1/` although `man pandoc` returns

```
man: can't resolve /usr/share/man/man1/pandoc.1.gz: No such file or directory
No manual entry for pandoc
```

Any assistance appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing, your have to extend your `PATH` environment variable to include

```
~/.cabal/bin
```

and then relogin afterwards.

This can be done in different ways. e.g.

```
editor ~/.bashrc
```

and add at the end

```
export PATH=~/.cabal/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

To give the usual sort of access (assuming ~/.cabal is world readable), do this:

```
sudo ln -s $HOME/.cabal/bin/* /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s $HOME/.cabal/man/man1/*.1 /usr/local/man/man1
sudo ln -s $HOME/.cabal/man/man5/*.5 /usr/local/man/man5
```

This allows `man pandoc`, `man pandoc_markdown`, `man markdown2pdf`.
You could also `cp` instead of `ln -s`, but then you'll have to repeat the copy when next you upgrade pandoc.